# Get the last argument from optparse python

Tags: python, linux, optparse

In optparse I am using two flags and I want to get the next value after flag. My requirement is I may give any of the option or even both the options some times so I am using these options like flags. I am using parser.parse_args() to get the value but the problem is I am getting output including some brackets.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import optparse
import sys
import os.path

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-p',  action='store_true', default=False, dest='DEST1', help="Some info")
parser.add_option('-k',  action='store_true', default=False, dest='DEST2', help="Some info")
options, infile = parser.parse_args()
print infile
```

O/P of file is

```
/myfile.py -p abc1
['abc1']
```

I need only file name as abc1

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  I ask because `argparse` is better but requires Python 2.7 or later.

Comment: I am using Python 2.6.6, I can even use argparse if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second value in the tuple returned by `parse_args()` is a list of remaining arguments.  If you only want to process the first one, it's simple:

```
print infile[0]
```

By the way, `argparse` is better than `optparse` if you're using Python 2.7 or later.  With `argparse` you can declare your positional arguments explicitly (see the documentation).  That means the parser can check that the user passed exactly one positional argument (for example), and also adds it to the `--help` output.